# mysql query execution/ optimization issue

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT cus.cust_id, cus.cust_name, cus.cust_lastname, cus.cust_zip,   
cus.cust_city, cus.cust_phone, cus.cust_email, cus.status,   
cus.cust_from, cus.cust_by, cus.added_date, zip.zipcode AS zipcode_val,
COUNT(ord.customer_id) AS custTotalOrders
FROM customers AS cus
LEFT JOIN orders AS ord ON cus.cust_id = ord.customer_id
LEFT JOIN zipcodes AS zip ON cus.cust_zip = zip.zip_id
WHERE cus.cust_id IS NOT NULL AND cus.cust_email IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY cus.cust_id, cus.cust_email
ORDER BY cus.added_date DESC
```

customers table has 69529 records

orders table has 295884 records

zipcodes table has 1257 records

**Customers Table structure & Index** 
[image]

**Orders Table structure & Index**
[image]

**Zipcode Table structure & Index**
[image]

**EXPLAIN QUERY** 
[image]

Above query is taking execution time more than 200 seconds / loading is going on.......

How to optimize above query?

How to solve this issue? 
Anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should create an index for both `ord.customer_id` and `cus.cust_zip`

Comment: @Solarflare I disagree with you about composite index `customers(cust_id, cust_email, date)`. I think it's meaningless to use it. WHERE and GROUP BY use `admin_customerlist`. So there is need only `customer (added_date)` for ORDER, `orders (customer_id)` and `customer(cust_zip)` for LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Talgat You are right, I misread that. `cust_id` is the primary key, so the group by is superficial (as the primary key is already unique) and an index on `added_date` could work, although I guess MySQL could prefer a full table scan+filesort here. The important index is indeed `orders(customer_id)`. But just to make sure there is no misunderstanding: MySQL can only use one index per (sub)table, so using all 3 indexes (the proposed two on `date_added` and on `cust_zip`, and the `admin_customerlist`-index) at the same time for this query is not possible.

Comment: @Solarflare As I can understand documentation MySQL can't use only `cust_id` and `admin_customerlist` at the same time. The optimizer will determine which of this 2 indexes will benefit the query. But there is possible to use `date_added` and `cust_zip` at the same time.

Comment: @Talgat No, unless for some special cases (e.g. `where a=1 or b=2` and you have an index on a and one on b), MySQL cannot use more than 1 index per table. It can however (and maybe that is what you mean) use a 2nd index if you use the table twice (e.g. `from table as a join table as b on a.id=b.id where a.x = 1` can use an index to join (to "b") and a different index to find the rows (in "a"); or something like `from a as a where exists (select * from a as a1 where a1.id > a.id)`). If not, you could link the documentation - but this discussion actually does not belong under this question.

Comment: @Solarflare Yes, you right, I'm wrong. Indexes for `date_added` and `cust_zip` are useless. Only index for `orders (customer_id)` will be usefull in this case. Also I suppose OP should remove `orders (by_customerlist_orderid)` as a duplicate for the Primary.

Comment: The query doesn't use index for `customers` table neither `Primary` or `admin_customerlist`. I guess it happens because of different column in ORDER BY. If you add `added_date` to the `admin_customerlist` MySQL should start to use it.